# Jquery, is there a way when the page that contains a specific id, the jquery function is triggered?

Tags: jquery

1. My goal is to trigger a jquery function when the page contains a specific id.
2. Or is there a way that the jquery triggered when it reads the last 2 url segments?

**Question 1**

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="furniture_features_03">
```

**Jquery**

```
$( "#furniture_features_03" ).function() {
    alert( "furniture_features_03 is in this page" );
});
```

**Question 2**

```
if the page url with /furniture/bills/
    then the jquery will trigger
```

For example, when I load this url: `https://stackoverflow.com/furniture/bills`, then the page will automatically pop up an alert message

Comment: No. however, you can run code at a certain time, and using that code determine whether or not the element exists. For example, on page load, or on document ready, or after a click event, after ajax, etc

Comment: Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I mean, any of the four i gave would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if it exists, use length, then use your code (jquery or plain javascript below):

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($( "#furniture_features_03").length > 0){
    alert( "furniture_features_03 is in this page" );
  }
});
```

**plain javascript:**

```
if(document.getElementById("furniture_features_03").length > 0){
     alert( "furniture_features_03 is in this page" );
}
```

**check the url:**

```
if(location.href.indexOf("/furniture/bills/") > -1){
    alert( "furniture_features_03 is in this page" );
}
```

Comment: wow this really works...and straight forward answer! but i would like to see another approach before i make any acceptable answer

Comment: @LearnProgramming I updated my answer to include 3 different options

Comment: tested all of them and it works like a charm! but what if the url has additional parameter like /furniture/bills/12? in `check the url` section? is it possible to ignore the parameter because i focus only the the first 2 segments which is `/furniture/bills` only

Comment: `IndexOf` actually searches the entire string for the "search string" so the URL could be 100 characters long and it wouldn't actually matter.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this..**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#furniture_features_03").length > 0 || window.location.href.includes('/furniture/bills/')){
    alert( "furniture_features_03 is in this page" );
  }
});
```

Comment: I have an error while using the code `Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href.contains is not a function`

Comment: you shouldn't get that error, but you could try replacing 'window.location.href.contains('/furniture/bills/')' with '(window.location.href.indexOf('/furniture/bills/') > -1)'

Comment: That should be ".includes()", not ".contains()".  (I frequently make the same mistake) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your great suggestions. I forgot that contains does not supportable by all browsers